# How to close triggered popup function in SetTimeout?

Tags: javascript, popup, settimeout, setinterval, thumbnails

I am customizing the code for a UNA CMS community site that uses PHP, JavaScript, jQuery, XML, etc. UNA has a unique problem in that you can attach link data using iFramely but the video thumbnail doesn't show in the timeline unless it is somehow reloaded. That triggers an CDN API call to fetch the full responsive data frame. There is a menu popup that creates a bubbling event which triggers the thumbnail to be fetched. I have been able to code a body injection which calls this and forces the video attachment thumbnail to appear using SetTimeout. I actually need to have it appear every (some) number of seconds (SetInterval?). Each new post is given a random ID number that changes, so I can't call the script when the post appears. The popup needs to close before it is opened again. This is normally done with a window/body click.

The following code opens the menu popup and forces the API call to generate the post thumbnail. I have to click the page to manually close it with this code:

```
<script>
$(function () { //code that works
    setTimeout(function () {
      menu_popup('timeline_menu', this);
    }, 23000);
});
</script>
```

I tried to call another script after that to close the popup but it didn't work. Here is that code:

```
<script>
function myFunction(el) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("menu_popup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
  setTimeout(() => {
    popup.classList.remove("show");
  }, 2000)
}
</script>
```

The following code was where I tried to use a timer to clear the popup. This did not work.

```
<script>
var timer;
function endAndStartTimer() {
  window.clearTimeout(timer); 
  timer = window.setTimeout(function(){menu_popup('timeline_menu', this);},20000); 
}
</script>
```

I really need to execute the above working function with a close function and be able to repeat the pair every number of seconds. I also need to hide the popup div so it doesn't interfere with what the user is doing on the site. I should be able to use CSS for that. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Good news! After sleeping on it, I figured out how to solve the problem. I called the script that was already working followed by a secondary function call to close the popup. It normally takes a couple seconds for the popup to completely form. I have the close set for one second after open. This achieves the thumbnail propagation desired and closes the event before the user can even see the popup open.

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
   menu_popup('blabla variables', this);
}, 22000);
</script>
<script>
setInterval(function(){
   menu_slide('blabla variables', this);
}, 23000);
</script>
```